# What is the most customisable apex-region type/ plug-in based on a table?

Tags: oracle-apex

I'd like to display the contents of a database table in a more interesting manner than just a table; different positioning, fonts, sizes, colours etc.

Is there a region type or plugin that can achieve that?

I tried the cards view but I it's still very limited (for example a minimum of 2 cards per row when I only need 1) Or maybe I should deploy it as a classic report and then use javascript to rearrange everything? edit: I also considered rendering the page with pl/sql and htp, but that seems overly complicated...

As I'm new to APEX, any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can create a bespoke region template with whatever HTML you want for a particular report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using an interactive report with a 'detail view'. That way you can use html+css and reference the data from the columns by using #column_name#. I'm really satisfied with it.

However the above answers are also very interesting! I definitely learned a lot experimenting with them.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a classic report and change the template under the attributes to something else.
[image]